# Is there any RAM disk software available for Apple II DOS 3.3?

Tags: apple-ii

I have an Apple IIc with 128 KB of RAM, about half of which goes unused. Since the IIc has only one drive, it would be convenient to use some of that unused RAM as a RAM disk. I know that this is available for ProDOS, but I use DOS 3.3. (And no, for various reasons I do not wish to switch to ProDOS.) Is there any RAM disk software or support currently available for DOS 3.3 systems?

Comment: Newest updates to ProDOS (yes, it is being maintained and enhanced) are pretty efficient on memory use, and has a lot of nice features over DOS 3.3. Certainly worth a look.

Comment: Glen Bredon's DOS Master lets you put DOS volumes on ProDOS disks, e.g. five 140K volumes on an 800K floppy. So you could create a ProDOS RAM disk and then put DOS on top of it. (In theory... not tested.) I don't know if that fits your requirements.

Comment: I remember an article in a German journal (Peeker) in the mid 1980s with a driver/patch for DOS 3.3 to use a bit less than 64 KiB as RAM disk.

Comment: Honestly, I can't even think of any DOS 3.3 software that used more than the base 64KB unless it was written to use a 3rd party card such as the Saturn 128K.

Comment: @BrianH As stated right in the post, "I do not wish to switch to ProDOS." Nor is, "you should try out a newer operating system" really an appropriate comment to be making in a retrocomputing forum.

Comment: I'm just throwing this up as a comment, because I haven't done my homework or tried this: but this link "https://archive.org/details/LOGIC_AppleII_Disk-DOS134" might prove useful?

Comment: @cjs Many retrocomputing hobbyists, like those my comment was directed toward, like almost nothing more than new software for their old hardware.

Comment: @Brian But is a question where someone specifically says they want to use DOS 3.3 really the best place to write about the virtues of ProDOS?

Comment: @BrianH et al: I'm curious about the ongoing maintenance and updates of ProDOS. Given it appears to have no connection to Apple, is it actually legal (i.e., blessed by Apple somehow)? I'm assuming it's the one at https://prodos8.com/ ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For many questions in the early days, the answer was Beagle Brothers. In this case [DiskQuik](https://archive.org/details/Beagle_Bros-DiskQuik/).

> DiskQuik
>
> DISK DRIVE EMULATOR by HARRY BRUCE and GENE HITE
>
> (REQUIRES APPLE IIe WITH EXTENDED 80-COLUMN CARD)
>
> AN IN-MEMORY "DISK DRIVE"
>
> DiskQuik acts like a disk drive connected to Slot 3, but it is much
>   faster,  quieter and more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

In 1982 there was a product made by Sorrento Valley Associates called
the App-l-Cache. It was both a language card and a ram disk. The nice
thing is they gave you the source code to all the drivers. So if you
know how to access the ram on the ii C maybe you can write a quick
ram disk driver following their lead. All info on my git hub page https://github.com/pfiliberti/app-l-cache/